# Inherited members automatically hidden by winforms generated code

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have two several child classes that link up to a parent class, all of which are winform classes. The problem lies in the auto generated code in all of the classes, which has the following common signature:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
//member inherited and hides parent's, however both derived and parent method are in designer sections (don't edit).
private new void InitializeComponent()
{
 //auto-generated logic
}
```

According to the compiler warning that I want to eliminate:

`Warning: 'Project.Windows.Forms.FirstChildClass.InitializeComponent()' hides inherited member 'Project.ParentClass.InitializeComponent()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.`

I need the child logic to hide the parent's, and I accomplished this in the code above by adding the new keyword. I am only worried that this might affect Winforms adversely; as the auto-generated comments state it should not be edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override parent members unless they are marked `virtual`.  If you hide the parent member, then when the method is called from the child class, then the child method will be used. The parent's method will only be called when the parent calls it.

If you can be more specific about which behavior in the parent class you want to "override" there may be another way to solve your problem.

Comment: @D Stanley The behavior I need for each child class is the logic in the child class itself. In this case, it is, however the compiler throws a warning to make sure I am actually trying to hide the parent's behavior (I am). My question is if adding the new keyword to trip the compiler warning will give me any trouble with wforms since the method definition is within the "do not edit" auto-generated code section. Note that both the parent and child InitializeComponent() methods are auto-generated